# SqlServer 2008 R2: Displaying first error within TRY/CATCH error management

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, error-handling, try-catch

I have inherited of a set o Stored Procedure in which some temporary tables are being created. To increase performance those tables are first created, filled in with data and only after that, the primary key is created. This consumes a lot of memory but creates the table way faster than creating the index right after the table.

The code is similar to the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#sample1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #sample1

CREATE TABLE #sample1 (
    ID INT
)

INSERT INTO #sample1
SELECT 1

INSERT INTO #sample1
SELECT 1


ALTER TABLE #sample1 ALTER COLUMN ID INT NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE #sample1
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_sample1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    ID asc
)
```

The sample above results in an error which is correct since the primary key was made duplicated for the purpose of the sample:

> Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 20 The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement
>   terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name
>   'dbo.#sample1____________________________________________________________________________________________________________0000000030B0' and the index name 'PK_sample1'. The duplicate key value is (1).
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 20 Could not create constraint. See
>   previous errors. The statement has been terminated.

In fact this returns 2 errors and when I call those stored procedures within a TRY/CATCH block, from a launcher SP, printing the error will only return the second:

```
BEGIN TRY

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#sample1') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #sample1

    CREATE TABLE #sample1 (
        ID INT
    )

    INSERT INTO #sample1
    SELECT 1

    INSERT INTO #sample1
    SELECT 1


    ALTER TABLE #sample1 ALTER COLUMN ID INT NOT NULL

    ALTER TABLE #sample1
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_sample1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        ID asc
    )


END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT Error_Message()
END CATCH
```

> Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Is there a way to retrieve the first error in the catch block? I really would like to avoid changing those SP. (sorry not to fiddle this, but sqlfiddle seems not to be working at the moment).

Comment: I think this is just a limitation in 2008. You can use `THROW` in 2012 onward to see all the error messages in a catch block, but I don't think you are going to be able to do it in 2008. Maybe i'm wrong though.